# Is there a point when "be fruitful and multiply" should no longer apply?

Tags: bible

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the commandment to multiply, and replenish the earth in effect today?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/847/is-the-commandment-to-multiply-and-replenish-the-earth-in-effect-today)

Well mainly I'm talking about the multiply bit...there are 7 billion people on the planet, is there any Christian reasoning that states that at some point you should take in existing-orphans instead of making more people?

Comment: The point would be reached in the following tombstone: "some have children, some have none. Here lies the mother / of twenty-one"